# Killing a python thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

I would like to kill somehow a running thread from my GUI application via setting an event, but I can't use a for loop in my thread so I need some other solution to check the event

I have the following situation.
In a tkinter gui when I click a button I start a thread and set a global variable.

```
self.thread = StoppableThread(caller=self)
self.thread.start()
is_running = 1
```

When I next click the button I check the global variable state and if it is already set I send a stop request:

```
if is_running:
    is_running = 0
    self.thread.stop()
```

This is my thread class:

```
import threading
from time import sleep


class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, caller=None):
        super(StoppableThread, self).__init__()
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()
        self.caller = caller

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_event.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop_event.is_set()

    def run(self) -> None:
        while True:
            # check for stop
            if self.stopped():
                break

            for i in range(10):
                sleep(1)
                print('Test')

            print('Worker done')
            break
```

Everything works if I change the while to a for loop, but because in this point in my business logic I doesn't have anything to loop for I need to check somehow different the state of the self.stopped(). Is there any way to check it in the while loop?

Or how can I achive this? I tried to use process instead of thread but it wasnt worked because of an error 'process can't pickle tkinter'.

Thank you for any help

Comment: You only check the `stopped` flag once, at the beginning, since you `break` after the first loop.  Just get rid of the `for` statement (but keep the contents), and delete the `print('Worker done')` and `break`.

Comment: The while loop runs only one iteration because of the `break` at the end of while loop.  Also it is better to post the for loop that works as you said *"Everything works if I change the while to a for loop"*.

Comment: It would help if you would at least describe what you are doing in this thread, to point you to a valid solution. As your question is written all you need to do is to delete the `break` statement and move `print('Worker done')` out of the enclosed space from your while-loop. Since you parse a `caller` and the error you have include points out that it is a widget that you are parsing, it is likely that your architecture still breaks, even with these changes.

Comment: Oh yes it is a good point to remove that break sorry
But still is not stopping.

Comment: @Thingamabobs I did'nt wanted to copy the whole Thread handling here.
But here is a describe for it. 

After I start the thread I read out some data from the database and pass them to an other handling class. In this class I do very long time processing tasks, sending requests to APIs etc etc. Some situation I want to break out from this and don't wait until for example all 20 request (1 request per hour) finish.

Comment: @Thingamabobs the more I think I  kinda feel this approach will not good to me. 
Because in the thread Inside the while loop I start other loops what are time consuming. And in the current way until the whole inside loop not finish there isn't a new iteration on the outer loop which checks for the stop. 
So I think I need to pass the stop request towards the inside loop too and check first there for the stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop will run forever until you set the flag:

```
    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped():
            sleep(1)
            print('Test')
```

You don't actually need an event.  A simple Boolean will do.

### FOLLOWUP

Here's an example based on your code that shows how this works:

```
import threading
from time import sleep

class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, caller=None):
        super(StoppableThread, self).__init__()
        self._stop_event = False
        self.caller = caller

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_event = True

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop_event

    def run(self) -> None:
        while not self.stopped():
            sleep(1)
            print('Test')
        print("exited")

thread = StoppableThread(caller=None)
thread.start()
sleep(5)
thread.stop()
sleep(1)
print("program ending")
```

Comment: Did you read the question or why do you propose something different without suggesting an alternative ?

Comment: Did YOU read the question?  He complained that he couldn't stop the thread when using a `while` loop.  The REASON he couldn't do that is because he was using the `while` loop incorrectly.  I show how to use it correctly.

Comment: *When I next click the button I check the global variable state and if it is already set I send a stop request* -- and you propose a simple boolean value, which isn't threadsafe by itself. Why would you do that ? Is python different in techs that you play with ?

Comment: I tried this. Changed the self._stop_event to False and in the stop() set to True and check like you suggested. But here is the output:

Test 0
Test 1
Stop requested
Test 2
Test 3
Test 4

Comment: Then you did it wrong.  I've updated the example.

Comment: Based on your suggestions now it is working. I had to tweak it a little but that just because to fit it into my code. But the pure solution you provided is the base, thank you!